# Are questions regarding "how to research things on the internet" on-topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I came across this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/659831/how-to-search-for-a-specific-program-with-a-specific-set-of-features

The title seemed innocent enough, but the bulk of the question seems like the answer they want is a software recommendation. But they obfuscate their off-topic-ness by simply stating "what I'm actually looking for is a **means** of finding a software recommendation."

I don't know if we approve of off-topic-ception (an off-topic question within a potentially off-topic question), but how do we handle questions regarding online research when it's general? Do those fall under learning material?

Comment: My thoughts on that are that they are off-topic (questions regarding *how to search the Internet*), because the Internet is not a piece of software or hardware one has in their computer (hence off-topic on SU). For the webapps stack that would be acceptable, I would assume.

Comment: As for the question itself, it seems like a product recommendation, with 2 *weak* prepositions (looking alike another program and being open-source)

Comment: @Moses - If a question is written in such a way where the author actually says they are looking for a software recommendation I flag for moderation for that exact reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software recommendations are off-topic no matter how you dress them up.  The VTC option gives a good reason why:

> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic **because they tend to become obsolete quickly**.

In this particular case, it's a software recommendation and should be closed.  Asking about how to do something (besides searching the internet) is on-topic.  See these two meta questions/answers for more details:

[How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software)

[How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Answer (score 0):

At the StackExchange network, we now have [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site in public beta, which is [quite healthy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) and can be definitely recommended.

So you can flag the question as off-topic and recommend the user to check at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (and add that AFTER they find nothing, they can post their question there).