# Can we stop advertising Crucial.com?

Tags: discussion, spam, advertising

The most top answer of [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](https://superuser.com/a/19005/87805) reads:

> Crucial is a good place to buy RAM and they have a System Scanner (Windows only) to analyse the memory that is present and recommend upgrades.

until I've edited this out to:

> You can use a System Scanner from Crucial to analyse the memory that is present and recommend upgrades.

And all other questions related to buying RAM are marked as duplicated of Crucial one.

---

Question about Crucial.com, really?

[Crucial.com gives me 2 answers for memory?](https://superuser.com/a/29012/87805)

Answers:

> If you use the scanner tool at Crucial, you are guaranteed to get the correct memory - otherwise you get a full refund.

Comments are like:

> Have you got a link for the refund claim?
>
> Sure do. crucial.com/support/crucialtop10.aspx "Find the Right Memory with the Crucial Memory Advisor™ tool We guarantee that the upgrades you find through the Crucial Memory Advisor tool will be compatible with your system, or your money back."

---

[Another](https://superuser.com/a/28945/87805):

> http://www.crucial.com/index.aspx
>
> Use the crucial memory scanner everyone is recommending

---

[Another](https://superuser.com/a/412478/87805):

> I really like using Crucial.com for memory upgrades

---

And many more. "Crucial.com" gives [over 50 results](https://superuser.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=%22crucial.com%22) ([>30 answers](https://superuser.com/search?q=%22crucial.com%22%20is%3Aanswer)). So I'm wondering, if people at Crucial are get paid for advertising their website? Apart of the scanner, they don't have anything useful.

---

Can the posts advertising and recommending the products from this website can be re-written and not valuable/useful answers removed?

Comment: While some of the answers that just point to crucial.com could be converted to comments there are often good ones that recommend them along with other useful information so not all should be deleted outright.

Comment: You flagged a comment of mine as spam for crucial.com? Are you saying moderators are spammers? (http://superuser.com/questions/420809/how-can-i-find-out-which-type-of-ram-i-need-for-my-laptop#comment481695_420809)

Comment: @slhck I'm not saying that, but product recommendation should be off-topic as far as I know.

Comment: *Asking* for product recommendations is considered off topic. You can recommend whatever you want as long as you adhere to our rules for quality answers.

Comment: @kenorb see [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for reference.

Comment: Thank for your help, I thought it was kind of spam performed by different people posting links to one site and bypassing the moderation, so the answers would looks perfectly fine. It's like answer to the question 'How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?' was basically 'Buy RAM at Crucial' (and making it the most up-voted makes the things suspicious).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether you like it or not, many people like Crucial.com, and we have no problem whatsoever with users of our site recommending Crucial.com, as long as:

- the answers consist of more than just a link and are valuable even if the link may break
- the users are not affiliated to the site

Crucial.com may even buy advertising space here. The only thing that wouldn't be allowed is them using fake accounts to promote their site, something that we would indeed consider as spam — but it has not occurred yet.

Comment: Agreed. There are certainly other options out there from other manufacturers and retailers, and that's the route I usually take to solve the RAM finding issue so I think it's a perfectly good answer. Users are allowed to recommend and link to any of them; no reason to enforce arbitrary -"equal opportunity" recommendations if one competitor comes up more often.