# General troubleshooting tips for Excel formulas and VBA

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, canonical-answer

I'm interested mainly in Excel and VBA, reading a lot of questions in these topics.

I often find questions like "formula doesn't work", "what is the problem with this code" for which there are a couple of things the asker should check, and these are generally asked in comments quite quickly (have you double checked that your output is really wrong? Have you tracked your formula, if yes where it fails? Which line of code gives the error message and what it is? Have you checked the values of the relevant variables in the immediate window? Not the same, but similar comment: Please make some effort to solve your problem, we aren't a few code writing service...).
Sometimes understanding the question takes more effort than actually solving it.

The Stack Exchange site has many canned messages;
e.g., the reasons for flags, and the options in the review queues.
It would be useful to have a similar boilerplate response to which we could refer for questions that exhibit the most common problems, instead of typing the same suggestions and clarifying questions each time.

How does Stack Exchange (or Super User in particular)
handle such "corporate knowledge" (standard responses to common issues)?
How can I contribute to such an article?
I don't feel myself enough experienced to do it alone.

Comment: Why are you submitting this information as a question? Why?

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear. I face a lot of poor quality questions and see how others (and me) just write several comments in order to make the question clear. Also there are typcial errors people do when they ask, I'd like to find a solution, but I'm new in meta to act alone, and also don't know what would be the right way to do it.

Comment: My immediate thought is that this sort of information would be useful to include in the [tag wiki](http://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel/info) for [microsoft-excel]. In its current state, the tag wiki doesn't include any information that's particularly useful to people asking questions on the site. Maybe this is a good jumping-off point for reconstructing the Excel tag wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mechanism that is commonly used is the obvious one —
answers to other questions. 
Sometimes somebody will ask a question that strikes to the heart of an issue
and draws large numbers of high-quality answers (and comments). 
Other times a seasoned veteran of the site will ask a generic question
simply for the purpose of having a place to hang answers on. 
These are commonly tagged [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq) (or [community-faq-proposed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq-proposed))
in Super User. 
(Similar questions on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) are called “canonical questions”. 
High-profile examples include:

- [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988)
- [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/q/100360/150988)
- [What can I do if I forgot my Windows 7 password?](https://superuser.com/q/72244/150988)
- [How do I recover or “undelete” files that I accidentally deleted?](https://superuser.com/q/449550/150988)
- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/q/284342/150988)
- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408) (on Unix & Linux)
- [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/23408) (on Unix & Linux)

[How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/150988) (tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on Meta Super User) is, similarly, referenced in many comments.

If you’re feeling ambitious, write a broad question along the lines of the above and immediately post a similarly all-encompassing answer.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I was looking for a more "official" way than just answer my question, but it's a good idea indeed.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought is that this sort of information would be useful to include in the [tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel/info) for [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel). In its current state, the tag wiki doesn't include any information that's particularly useful to people asking questions on the site. Maybe this is a good jumping-off point for reconstructing the Excel tag wiki.

While new users are unlikely to read the tag wiki before asking, this will at least give reviewers the ability to point to a link rather than repeating the same troubleshooting/asking advice on every poor question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That also sounds well, however, I think I already have more idea than that could be written in the tag wiki.