# Questions Asking for Product Recommendations

Tags: discussion

Did I handle [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1005718/hardware-firewall-for-small-scale-comapny/1005720?noredirect=1#comment1392212_1005720) correctly? A new / dupe / green user asking for product recommendations..

Comment: [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that linked question, it looks like you were looking to recommend software in a comment to the answerer.  Which, if you want to do that in a comment, I see no harm - but it'd probably be better left to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

In general, you are allowed to recommend products in your answers if they help resolve the problem.  The main "no product requests" rule is in place to prevent people *asking* for product recommendations ("I want software that does 'X'" kind of questions).

If you are going to recommend software in an *answer*, include along with it how to use the software to help solve the problem at hand.  Also, including how you are affiliated with software you are recommending is a good idea as well (especially if you are involved in the product's creation/sales, etc.).

Doing these will help keep you answer from just looking like spam. :)

Comment: This was hardware. Assume the same applies....

Comment: @DavidVernon - Yes

Comment: And, while I guess this isn't particularly applicable to hardware, it should be noted that the term "product" is interpreted very broadly, to include free software, online services (e.g., webmail sites), and books.  You may link to a site that authoritatively answers a question only if you include the essential parts of the answer in your post and provide the link for reference.  (And, if you need to replicate several pages of a source to answer the question, that's a red flag that the question is too broad (and should be closed).)