# Bad audit answer

Tags: discussion

I just failed this [audit answer](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/543495):

> You can use ClickMonitorDDC http://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net this is
>   a great tool for adjusting brightness and contrast of external
>   monitors, but you can also adjust brightness of internal LCD, and this
>   tool has an option (set by default) to use the same brightness for on
>   battery and plugged in. You do not have to really work with this tool,
>   simply run it once, there will be autostart (set by default), and the
>   tool sits silently in the taskbar, but recognizes the change between
>   on battery or plugged in, and it will ensure always same brightness.

As far as I can tell it:

1. Answers the question
2. It is not spam (ClickMonitorDDC is freeware)
3. Meets the requirements for recommending software ([How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330))

Although it has been downvoted (and deleted) it is not a bad answer and should not be used for reviews.

It is not clear **why** it was deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might not have been obvious spam, but the users only other interaction with the site was [another near-advert](https://superuser.com/questions/961449/increase-brightness-of-external-monitor/1066133#1066133) for this same piece of software a month and a half before (10K only link).  While normal users cannot see this it suggests that the poster may either be the author or an overly enthusiastic user.

Neither posts are particularly good quality, well formatted or well explained.  Together with their only interest being this software does not cast them in a good light, we'd prefer objective reviews across a variety of things rather than a laser like focus on one product.

Resurrecting an old question to belch the name of your favourite piece of software takes care and attention, something that was not done here.

In all honesty if *all* I'd seen was your review post, I'd have given it a pass as well.  As it was, the user has a bit of a suspicious history.

Comment: Hehe. I see I added an appropriate comment on his **other** earlier answer (your link) how to recommend software ... so he learned something ... :)

Comment: He learnt *something*, just not enough... ;)