# Link only answer with many steps

Tags: discussion, answers

This is [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1206009/456385).

I've searched a bit in meta and I think I've got a feel of what should be done with link-only answers.

However, in that question, there are some options for real-time collaborating. I only mentioned a few, but there are too many steps to be included in the post, so I leave it for the OP to choose what's best for his situation.

I'm not whining about the downvote, but I really want to know what can I do to improve the post, given the nature of the answer requires too many steps to be included in the answer.

Comment: You could at least write a one paragraph summary for each of the links,

Comment: Link-only answers should be deleted.  I wouldn't consider your the current revision of your answer to be a link-only answer.  Although if you were going to reference a answer.microsoft.com answer you should quote and cite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) is the most relevant meta post.

In this case, there's nothing too terrible with your answer, there's a few points.

Firstly, that he's using office 2016/365 *probably* should be explicit in the question. Right now, it isn't. If he's on an older version "use a newer major version you don't have" would be written differently.

*Exact* version numbers would be nice since this feature will be drifting into non fast ring versions eventually.

I've often found if you've used this feature, its neat to actually "build your own tutorial" on how to use a tool, and try to make a more elegant set of instructions on how to do it.

I don't consider this downvotable, but that's my read on it.

Comment: It is downvoted before I revised it to the current version, so I understand if someone hated the answer with only links on it.

Comment: @Vylix *Nobody* hated your answer they simply thought it should be improved.  You shouldn't take a single downvote (or any amount of votes) so personal

Comment: I *probably* should have mentioned the parable of [Tim Post's Keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/135565) .

Comment: @Ramhound ah, I mean "hate" in "dislike". I also downvote short answer that seems lazy, so I understand nothing personal. It's a good thing I can actually learn something from this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ah, thanks for the link. It really cheers me up :)