# My answer was deleted: why, and what should I do now?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Super User post: [How do I play audio though jackd from console?](https://superuser.com/questions/1095877/how-do-i-play-audio-though-jackd-from-console/1266289#1266289)

Hi.

I submitted an answer to superuser, but my answer was deleted. I've checked the list of possible causes for post deletion, but I still can't work out why my answer was deleted:

(from https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)

- commentary on the question or other answers: no
- asking another, different question: no
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses: no, but see below
- exact duplicates of other answers: definitely not!
- barely more than a link to an external site: no
- not even a partial answer to the actual question: no

The question makes reference to play, aplay and paplay, which are not so much "generalised media players", but are instead simple light-weight command-line tools more intended for use in testing/debugging whether the appropriate sound servers are working.

As a result, I believe that jack-play is the correct answer to the question (it, too, is *not* a generalised media player - it's a light-weight tool for testing a jack server)

No other prior post (either comment or answer) makes reference to jack-play, so I'm contributing new information and not just duplicating something.

I understand that the question was already "answered" when I submitted my answer, and that might have contributed to its deletion. I also understand that I started my answer with the words "I have exactly the same question..." and that this attempt at empathy may have rung the "Me too!" warning bells.

In my defence, my answer did receive a "This answer is useful" upvote before it was deleted.

Please note that I am *not* asking why my answer is not the accepted answer - I'm asking why it was deleted.

With my answer deleted, the entire web page makes no reference to jack-play, and I think that this is a problem. Should I attempt to fix this problem, and if so, how?

[image]

Comment: I can't see your deleted answer (my rep is too low) but the question itself is off-topic (seeking a product or service) which might be the reason.

Comment: @Burgi It was a “me too” answer that was a software recommendation that didn’t meet the minimum quality qualifications and was a link-only answer

Answer (score 3):

While less than obvious - the answer relied *heavily* on links to make any sense. To me, its still a link only answer (and look a lot like the canonical post on [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)). The rule of thumb is "does this make sense even without the links?", and your answer does not.

Good software recommendation answers kinda go a little deeper than "look at this and this" - you might want to talk about *how* to use said software to solve the problem. We have a more indepth post on [this here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

So, add more detail. Talk about how it solves the problem. Give some examples of use of this tool in solving said problem. Then flag for undeletion (preferably referring this post in a custom reason) and we'll undelete it.